# ¢tRÂà³Ab.Ÿân TXT files: how to switch from weird characters back to normal?

Tags: windows-7, text-editors, encoding, file-corruption, character-encoding

So, I have on a flash drive a txt file generated in Cyrillic (my own work, own pen drive), a few years old. Now I needed to open it, only to see this kind of mess:

[image: mess].

I wonder why is this happening and how can I restore it back to normal.. I tried saving it under Unicode and UTF-8 encoding, even some MS-DOS format (an option from Wordpad) but it makes no difference at all.

Comment: Your document appears to have been saved in KOI-8 encoding; you will need to find a way to translate it from that encoding to Unicode.

Comment: You may find https://2cyr.com/decode/ to be useful.

Comment: I hope you have a copy of the original file, because saving the "messy" file using a different encoding just makes the problem worse.

Comment: Open it in MS Word Rus with auto-detect encoding or manual encoding selection (KOI-8r, CP866, etc. - try until correct pre-view) and then re-save in encoding you need (do not save over!). Or use any online recoder and determine text's original encoding.

Comment: @Johan Myréen Of course, I figured this out and saved them as new files

Comment: @Akina "Open it in MS Word Rus with manual encoding selection"
Thanks, this worked.

Comment: @Akina "re-save in encoding you need (do not save over!)"

Though I need to mention for the benefit of others with the same (quite common) issue who may stumble upon this thread, this does not work if you re-save as another txt file, even though with the proper encoding - there was again that mess of characters. Only saving as a Word or rtf file helps.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin
Thank you too, good that such thing exists, even though I did not need to use it this time, it may be helpful in future :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is referred to as [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).  In short, the application you are opening the file with is using the wrong encoding to try and read the file.  The standard fix is to use a transcoding tool, either online or offline (though I know of no free ones for Windows which work offline), or open the document in an application that lets you set the encoding and save it through that as the desired encoding.

As a somewhat hacky alternative, if you can save the file *without* modifying the encoding, you can change the extension to `.eml`, [format it like an email message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_format), make sure the `Content-Type` header specifies the correct encoding, and then open the resulting file in a good email client (pretty much anything except Outlook or Windows Mail) and copy the text out of there to a text editor and save it.

For future reference, the generally accepted method of avoiding this is to save files as either UTF-8 or UTF-16 (UTF-8 is usually preferred, as it's better supported by most platforms other than Windows than UTF-16).

In particular, your file does indeed appear to be encoded using KOI-8 (determined based on the statement that the text is Cyrillic and the apparent distribution of actual characters), with the application apparently interpreting it as ISO-8859-1 or Windows codepage 1252(determined simply based on what is being displayed, plus the fact that these are standard fallback encodings for many devices).

Comment: Many text editors (e.g. Notepad2) act as transcoding tools: you can force them to open a file using whatever encoding you specify, and then save as UTF-x.

Comment: @grawity However, Notepad and Wordpad don't support this, so unless you've got a third-party text editor on Windows, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try editor [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) (or SynWrite), free.

- open this txt file
- click statusbar field with encoding name (e.g. ANSI), "Reload as"
- find encoding which makes OK text
- when found encoding, click statusbar field with encoding name, "Convert to"
- use UTF8
- save file with UTF8